# How to pass the article id to the "View Article" Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm  a PHP Web Developer. When I create a view article page I was passing the `id` in `GET` something like `article.php?id=10`

But now in android if I have an activity which views the article, how to pass to it the article ID to select it's data from the database?

What is my best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the article id in the intent when calling the ArticleActivity. Here is how to do it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ArticleActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("articleId", articleId);
startActivity(intent);
```

In this code, this is the context of your current activity; articleId is your articleId you want to pass. Then, when you want to retrieve it in the ArticleActivity, you do this in onCreate of the activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int articleId = extras.getInt("articleId");
```

Thats it! Hope that helped.

Comment: can i pass Objects?? i mean if i selects all the articles into Article[] can i pass the target article object to avoid selecting it's data again???

Comment: You can definitely do that, but I wouldn't recommend it. There are a few limitations on how much data you can send. Best option would be to send the articleId and query the database again.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have 2 Activities. The first one has a list of articles. When you click on an article you start your second activity.

In you onClick() method:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("id", 10);
startActivity(i);
```

In you second activity:

```
int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0); //0 is a default value
```

Comment: can i pass Objects?? i mean if i selects all the articles into Article[] can i pass the target article object to avoid selecting it's data again???

Comment: You can pass a Serializable object. There is a size (as in memory) limit though.